# Error: Failed to load external entity "http://......."

Tags: r, web-scraping, powerbi

**Problem**

I am trying to replicate the web scraping done in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tuNuxCjBU3U).

Ultimately, I want to run the code in Power BI's R Script editor but error I'm getting says that I don't have the package `data.table` installed. I then tried to run the code in RStudio and made sure I installed the necesseary packages and libraries. When I run the code with `http` I get the error `Failed to load external entity "http://......."`.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any troubleshooting advice?

**Code**

```
library(data.table)
library(XML)

pages <- c(1:25)

urls <- rbindlist(lapply(pages, function(x) {
  url <- paste("http://www.r-users.com/jobs/page/",x,"/", sep="")
  data.frame(url)
}), fill=TRUE)

jobLocations <- rbindlist(apply(urls , 1, function(url) {
  doc1 <- htmlParse(url)
  locations <- getNodeSet(doc1,'//*[@id="mainContent"]/div[2]/ol/li/dl/dd[3]/span/text()')
  data.frame(sapply(locations , function(x) { xmlValue(x)}))
}), fill=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same error here, but it seems to work with another libraries, like `xml2` and `rvest`, so try following snippet:

```
library(data.table)
library(rvest)
library(xml2)

pages <- c(1:2)

urls <- rbindlist(lapply(pages, function(x) {
  url <- paste("http://www.r-users.com/jobs/page/",x,"/", sep="")
  data.frame(url)
}), fill=TRUE)

jobLocations <- data.table::rbindlist(apply(urls, 1, function(url) {    
    nodes <- html_nodes(read_html(url), xpath = '//*[@id="mainContent"]/div[2]/ol/li/dl/dd[3]/span/text()')
    text <- html_text(nodes)
    data.frame(text)
}), fill=TRUE)
```

Comment: When I run the above code I get the error message: Error in read_xml(x, encoding = encoding, ..., as_html = TRUE, options = options) : argument "x" is missing, with no default. Where in the functions is "x" missing?

Comment: I've updated the answer to avoid pipe operator, so `tidyverse` package is not needed. I only had to `install.packages("data.table")` and `install.packages("rvest")`.